# Transform a loop for parallelisation

Tags: algorithm, loops, parallel-processing

What other loop transformations that I can do with this code to increase the amount of potential parallelism?

The code is here :

```
for (int i=10; i<N; i++)
{
    A[i] = B[i] * 14.3 / A[10];
    C[i] = C[i-1] + C[i-2];
}
```

What I have done so far is using loop peeling :

```
A[10] = B[10] * 14.3 /A[10]
C[10] = C[10-1] + C[10-2];
for(int i = 11 ; i<N; i++)
{
    A[i] = B[i] * 14.3 / A[10];
    C[i] = C[i-1] + C[i-2];
 }
```

That solves the first line, but is there anyway I can transform the second line inside the loop?

Comment: The `A[i] = B[i] * 14.3 / A[10];` is irrelevant to your question, since there are no dependencies in it, neither does it yield any dependencies on the other line.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
for (int i=10; i<N; i++)
    {
    A[i] = B[i] * 14.3 / A[10];
    C[i] = C[i-1] + C[i-2];
    }
```

so `A[10]` is special case as you found out already and `C` is not depending on `A,B` and using floating or fixed point (so you can use pre-computed constant without big accuracy loss) so you can split into:

```cpp
// serial
A[10] = B[10] * 14.3 / A[10];
c0 = 14.3 / A[10];
// thread 1
for (int i=11; i<N; i++) A[i] = B[i] * c0;
// thread 2
for (int i=10; i<N; i++) C[i] = C[i-1] + C[i-2];
```

now `B` is independent on `A` so you can do the first loop in parallel on as many threads as you want (up to N-11)...

the second loop is dependable on previous results so you can not split it unless some more knowledge on the C and resulting accuracy is known.

resulting in:

```cpp
// serial
A[10] = B[10] * 14.3 / A[10];
c0 = 14.3 / A[10];
for (i0=11,i1=11+(N-11)/M,j=1;j<=M;j++,i0=i1,i1=11+j*(N-11)/M)
 // threads 1...M 
 for (int i=i0; i<i1; i++) A[i] = B[i] * c0;
// thread M+1
for (int i=10; i<N; i++) C[i] = C[i-1] + C[i-2];
```